# React native build cannot find jar

Tags: react-native

We have a project, which compiles and run for everybody EXCEPT me. I have exactly the same code, I try to run it exactly the same way, but the log says:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-camera:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find core.jar (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0).   Searched in the following locations:
>         https://artifactory.mycompany.eu/artifactory/mvn-libs-all/com/google/zxing/core/3.3.0/core-3.3.0.jar

I changed the url above (only the company name), but i checked, and the jar is presented there.

This jar is necessary for react-native-camera node module.

I have already:

- run npm cache clean --force
- run gradlew clean
- deleted the whole project, checked out the source code, installed
  node modules, tried to run

But nothing helped.

EDIT:

project/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

rootProject.ext.isRelease = project.hasProperty('buildForDebug')? false:true

def RNfile = new File("$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/package.json")
rootProject.ext.rnVersion = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(RNfile.text).version

artifactId = project.artifactId

allprojects {
    println "release $isRelease"
    //version = "${project.version}-${isRelease ? project.property('build.number') : 'SNAPSHOT'}"
    version = "${project.version}-${ project.hasProperty('build.number') ? project.property('build.number') : '0'}"
    group = project.groupId
    println "coordinates: $group:$artifactId:$version"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                    details.useVersion rootProject.ext.rnVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }  
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

subprojects { project ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if (project.name.contains('react-native-')) {
            project.tasks.collect { task ->
                if (task.name == 'lint') {
                    task.enabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

project/android/app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.androidSignKeystorePassword = (project.hasProperty('keystorePassword'))? project.property('keystorePassword') : System.properties['android.keystorePassword']
project.ext.androidSignKeyPassword = (project.hasProperty('keyPassword'))? project.property('keyPassword') : System.properties['android.keyPassword']
project.ext.androidSignKeyAlias = (project.hasProperty('keyAlias'))? project.property('keyAlias') : System.properties['android.keyAlias']

configurations { 
    keystore
}

dependencies {
    keystore "eu.dorsum.cm.config:jenkins-android-keystore:1@jks"
}

rootProject.ext.signApp = project.hasProperty('signKeyAlias') && project.hasProperty('keystore-android-password')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
                    details.useVersion rootProject.ext.rnVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }

    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "26.1.0"
                    }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    root: "$rootDir",
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dbit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName project.version
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        if (!project.hasProperty('buildForDebug')) {
            archivesBaseName = "${rootProject.name}-${versionName}"
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile files(project.configurations.keystore.collect { it }).singleFile
            storePassword project.ext.androidSignKeystorePassword
            keyAlias project.ext.androidSignKeyAlias
            keyPassword project.ext.androidSignKeyPassword
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    variantFilter { variant ->
        // ignores unwanted build types
        // no release type from development branch, no debug type from release branch
        // (ignore = release type XOR release version)
        setIgnore(variant.buildType.name.equals('release') ^ isRelease)
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-view-overflow')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])  
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:${rootProject.ext.rnVersion}"  // From node_modules
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
           exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
           implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'
           implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
                force = true
           }
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}
```

If you have any suggestion, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution was running the following command in the projectName/android folder:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

The strange thing for me is that *gradlew clean was not enough*.

According to this documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache#clear_the_build_cache:

> "Similar to the Android plugin's clean task that clears your project’s
>   build/ directories, you can run the cleanBuildCache task to clear your
>   project’s build cache."

Based on this information, it is obvious that something went wrong in my build cache and that caused the problem.

**I also had to delete the node_modules folder, and install all node modules again.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss repository in Gradle to get `com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0`

You need open Android Studio with project in folder `/android` of your react-native project.

and edit file `build.gradle` of project

like this  [image: Like this]

and add `google()` and `jcenter()` to `respository` of `buildscript` and `allprojects`

like this

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It was a good suggestion, might help to other people, but unfortunately, in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: could you post 2 build.gradle file in your project ? I see that might be a missing repository or Android Studio cannot access to repository.